# How to get number of sales from Facebook ad insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am working with the Facebook Marketing API and am interested in knowing the number of people that made a purchase after interacting with a specific ad/ad campaign.  So for example, I want to see for a given time period that Campaign X had a reach of Y, and of those Y users Z made a purchase.  Reach is straightforward, but I am confused as to how one calculates purchases.

The [insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/fields/v2.12) allows me to calculate `action_values` for a campaign, which should give number of actions by `action_type`.  [Looking at](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-action-stats/) `action_type`, I see a number of possibly relevant fields:

`commerce_event.purchase`:  Commerce purchases

`offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchases`:  Purchases

`onsite_conversion.purchase`:  On-Facebook purchases

But wait, there's more.  Under grouped action types, we have:

`offsite_conversion`

`offline_conversion`

`onsite_conversion`

`purchase`

I would think that adding offsite and onsite purchases would work, but then what is a "commerce purchase"?  The grouped action that is just called purchase is also tempting.  How can I get what I'm after?

Also, is there any way to get dollar amounts associated with these purchases?  The insights API has a field for ROAS which means it must be recording revenue somewhere.  How can I get at that?  And does ROAS include on-Facebook purchases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the way you have the measurement integrated on your website (or mobile app).

Typically you'd use Facebook Pixel (setup and details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/pixel-with-ads/conversion-tracking), which sends events from your website to FB.

Once you have the pixel set up and you can see FB receiving events, you can proceed to loading the stats through Insights API.

Most used action type is `offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase`, but it really depends on which evens you integrated on your website. There's a lot to choose from.

Semantics of those metrics is as follows:

- `actions` - counts of actions

  - `value` - actually **count** of actions, in default attribution model
- `action_values` - values according to action type, e.g. purchased goods price

  - `value` - value of actions, in default attribution model

If you're interested in different attribution models, there are additional fields on `actions` and `action_types` that have those numbers broken down to after-click/view.

Comment: I'm working on an app that integrates with FB, so I need to come up with some sort of general rule for counting conversions and revenue.  If I add commerce, onsite, and offsite purchases is it possible I would be double counting (or missing anything) ever?  Thanks for explaining the difference between action and action_values, makes sense.

Comment: Summing values across channels (offsite/onsite/app/...) should be fine. You may also take a look at "Grouped Action Types" as those should do the summing for you. Either way I suggest checking on some real cases to be sure. Plus, people aren't always good at setting up the measurement and your math can easily get broken by _their_ mistake :-/